# Notepad ++ regex. Finding and replacing with wildcard, but without allowing any spaces?

Tags: regex, notepad++, wildcard

I have something like this in txt

```
[[asdfg]] [[abcd|qwerty]]
```

in a row, but I want it to look like that

```
 [[asdfg]] [[qwerty]]
```

using wildcards ( [[.*\| ) when trying to search, results in it finding the whole line up to the "|" Not allowing it to have a space in between should work, but I don't know how to do that.

Edit 1

It's from a wikipedia dump, so the first part is the word in it's basic form and the second is how it fits into the sentence. Something like `[[I]] [[be|was]] [[at]] [[the]] [[doctor]]` And I want to change it into normal sentences

```
[[I]] [[was]] [[at]] [[the]] [[doctor]]
```

Edit 2

I found somewhat of a solution. I just put every word in a new line, did the first regex and then deleted newlines. That did kinda mess up my spacing though...

Comment: should it always find same/repeated characters like `c'|c` , `a'|a` ?

Comment: No. It's from a wikipedia dump, so the first part is the word in it's basic form and the second is how it fits into the sentence. Something like
[[I]] [[be|was]] [[at]] [[the]] [[doctor]]. And I want to change it into normal sentences.

Comment: how `[[I]] [[be|was]] [[at]] [[the]] [[doctor]]` should be replaced?

Comment: [[I]] [[was]] [[at]] [[the]] [[doctor]]
The rest of formatting is obvious to me.

Comment: You wrote `.*` where `\w+` would have been more appropriate. Or at least make it [non-greedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_matching): `.*?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\[\[\w+\|(\w+)\]\]
```

Replace with:

```
[[$1]]
```

Make sure you choose `Regular expression` at the bottom before you click `Replace All` in Notepad++.

Comment: It says it can't find the text.

Comment: It should find anything similar to this `[[c'|c]]`. Did you choose `Regular expression` at the bottom before you click `Replace All` ?

Comment: I was not clear enough with the code though... It's not really a c'|c these are two different words. Sorry.

Comment: It is my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in one run like so

```
\[{2}(?:(?!\]{2}).)+?\|([^\]]+)
```

This needs to be replaced by

```
[[$1
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/FDJmU2/1/).

---

Broken down this says:

```
\[{2}             # match [[
(?:(?!\]{2}).)+?  # do not overrun ]]
\|                # |
([^\]]+)          # capture anything not ] into group 1
```

Afterwards, you'll only need to replace the open brackets and the content of group `$1`